# i am trying to pass the title form model to a template for nav dropdown but it is working in main html page but not showing others

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

i am trying to create a nav dropdown that with the model titles but it is showing drop down on the main html page but it is not showing other pages and also i tried to make a one header html template in it also its is not showing the titles , so how can i pass the objects to multiple template

**my template drop down**:

```
<li class="menu-has-children"><a href="#services">All Services</a>
  <ul style="display: inline;">
    {% for detailinfo in detail.all %}
      <li><a href="{% url 'details' services.slug %}">{{ detailinfo.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</li>
```

**my view**:

```
def details(request, services_slug):
    q = services.objects.filter(slug=services_slug)
    if q.exists():
        q=q.first()
    else:
        return HttpResponse("<h1> page not found </h1>")

    detail = {'detail': q}

    return render(request, 'detail.html', detail,)
```

i want to add these objects in detail page

```
def homepage(request):

aboutinfo = aboutpage.objects
servicesinfo = services.objects
programinfo = prgm.objects

return render(request, 'index.html', {'aboutinfo': aboutinfo, 'servicesinfo': servicesinfo, 'programinfo': programinfo})
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{% for detailinfo in detail %}` in the template?

Comment: no i want to iterate the objects so it is detail.all

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
If you want showing `detail` for other pages, the pages view must have `detail`.
My method is to collect the variables I use everywhere and combine them with all views.
For example;

```
# general.py
payload = {'detail': x_variable, 'loremipsum': 2}
```

this is my general payload and i import this payload every view in my project.
then in all views;

```
# your view for example
def details(request, services_slug):

.........

detail = {'detail': q}

detail.update(my_imported_payload)

return render(request, 'detail.html', detail,)
```

**IMPORTANT EDIT : There was a better way to do this. Please search the context processors in django!**